# Intel CPU microcode update fails everytime

Tags: linux, cpu, centos-5

I have a few XenServer VMs all running CentOS 5.5. Some are 32-bit and others are 64-bit.

Every time they boot, the following message appears:

**Applying Intel CPU microcode update: [FAILED]**

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably happens because the OS is running inside a VM and therefore can't apply CPU microcode updates. As for how to fix it, I have no idea. Does this message prevent any meaningful work or does it merely disturb you? In the latter case you can safely ignore it.

Comment: This sounds very sensible, a virtual machine should neither need nor be able to apply microcode updates as that (I would have thought) should be handled by the host.

Comment: "As the virtual machine is running on virtual CPUs there is no point updating the microcode. Disabling the microcode update for your virtual machines will stop this error: " https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Microcode_error_during_guest_boot.html

Answer (score 4):

If you want to prevent the Intel CPU microcode from starting at boot, you can disable it as follows: (Run the command as root)

`# chkconfig microcode_ctl off`

This will prevent the microcode service from trying to apply the update at boot, since it will fail on your VMs every time.

Answer (score 3):

On a CentOS 6 installation, microcode_ctl doesn't seem to be invoked via the /etc/init.d (chkconfig) mechanism any more.  I achieved the same effect by uninstalling the package:

```
# rpm --erase microcode_ctl
```

*(I know the original question was centOS 5.5, but a search brought me here...)*